# cdkDropListDropped="drop($event)" is not firing, mat table with datasource

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

This is the situation I have, I need to make a column drag n' drop functionality using mat-table and cdkDragDrop from Angular (working with Angular 8).

Here's what I have so far.

Inside a component.html I have:

```html
<mat-table cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="column.name">

    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="x">
      {{column.title}}
    </mat-header-cell>

    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[column.name] }}</mat-cell>

  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="tableHeaderRow" #tableHeaderRow></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

and inside a component.ts I have:

```js
export class TestClass implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phoneNumber', 'address', 'points', 'Details'];
  .
  .
  .
  columns: any[] = [{
        name: 'id',
        title: 'Id'
      },
      {
        name: 'firstName',
        title: 'FirstName'
      },
      {
        name: 'lastName',
        title: 'LastName'
      },
      {
        name: 'email',
        title: 'Email'
      },
      {
        name: 'phoneNumber',
        title: 'PhoneNumber'
      },
      {
        name: 'address',
        title: 'Address'
      },
      {
        name: 'points',
        title: 'Points'
      },
      {
        name: 'Details',
        title: 'Details'
      },
    ]
    .
    .
    .
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop < any[] > ) {
    moveItemInArray(this.displayedColumns, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

}
```

This is just a simple test code I managed to find on internet [Example on stackblitz I found](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-column-reorder)
The problem is, I can't manage to get the line `(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"` to fire an event in the "drop" function in ts. I tried the functionality without table and it's working, it's firing the event (and "drop" function), but inside the table, it's not working.

I wonder if any of you had encountered a similar problem and if you managed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Same issue here, but a different situation: I have a cdkDropList positioned absolute and the `cdkDropListDropped` event is not firing. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet Sergiu, but to be honest, I've had some other work that needed to be done, so i poke at this here and there, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem using Angular 9.1.12.

I've found this example with a previous version of Angular, but using the same code it didn't work for me ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-columns-draggable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)).

So I used this workaround (making droppable the entire table) and it works:

```js
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource" cdkDropList cdkDropListLockAxis="x"
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" matSort
    (cdkDropListDropped)="dropListDropped($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of headers; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol.field}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="{name: disCol.field, columIndex: colIndex}"
            mat-sort-header>
            {{disCol.field}}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row "> {{row[disCol.field]}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
   [...]
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, add this method in ts file for those who does not know it,

`dropListDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) { moveItemInArray(this.displayedColumns, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex); }`